# How to turn back to the old one-handed mode?

Tags: xiaomi, android-12

I have Xiaomi 11 note Pro 5g , and yesterday it was updated from android 11 to android 12.
I was surprised that the One-Handed mode feature was updated as well but the new update is so annoying and can't be helpful for anything, its totally useless.

I just get half screen and I cannot scroll up nor down, it does not resize the screen width which is annoying as well.

Can I get back to the old version of the feature without downgrade the android version ?